# What directory does CURL to be saved to in Xampp?

Tags: curl, installation, windows-vista, libcurl

I am trying to get started with CURL.  I am running windows vista and have xampp installed.  I downloaded the curl zip and extracted this but the curl executable when run just does a quick flash of a command promp then disappears.  where am I going wrong on this curl install?

Answer (score 2):

curl is not a program with a graphical interface : it's a command-line tool.

This means you'll have to :

- open a command-line window
- navigate, with the `cd` command, to the directory in which `curl.exe` is
- and, then, call `curl.exe`, passing it some parameters on the command line.

Comment: Appreciate your response. I am up and running now. I chose to go through my hosting provider HostGator.com.